# MySQL SELECT JOIN returns unknown column in field list

Tags: mysql

This Query returns 'Unknown position.name in field list'.

**dummy_schema.positions**

[image: dummy_schema.positions]

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
'id', userData.id,
'email', userData.email,
'first_name', userData.first_name,
'last_name', userData.last_name,
'mood', userData.mood,
'uuid', userData.uuid,
'role', userData.role,
'rawRole', IF(userData.role = 'cls_administrator', 'Administrator', IF(userData.role = 'cls_moderator', 'Moderator', IF(userData.role = 'cls_member', 'Member', ''))),
'position', userData.position,
'rawPosition', position.position,
'lastSeen', userData.lastSeen,
'added', userData.added) AS profile

FROM dummy_schema.users AS userData
LEFT JOIN dummy_schema.positions AS position ON userData.position = position.id
WHERE id = 1;
```

> MySQL V6.3 Workbench

Comment: There isn't a `name` column in your `positions` table.

Comment: Your query doesn't reflect your error message.  There's no `position.name` anywhere on your query, yet you get the error message.  That means you don't post the right query.  Isn't this the same question as the messed up question you posted earlier???  Same problem as previous question, if you don't post the query that reflects the error, no one can help you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to give `dummy_schema.positions` table other aliases name instead of `position` because your alias is `position` but there is a column has same name `position` that will let DB engine confuse.

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT
(
    'id', userData.id,
    'email', userData.email,
    'first_name', userData.first_name,
    'last_name', userData.last_name,
    'mood', userData.mood,
    'uuid', userData.uuid,
    'role', userData.role,
    'rawRole', IF(userData.role = 'cls_administrator', 'Administrator', IF(userData.role = 'cls_moderator', 'Moderator', IF(userData.role = 'cls_member', 'Member', ''))),
    'position', userData.position,
    'rawPosition', p.position,
    'lastSeen', userData.lastSeen,
    'added', userData.added
) AS profile  
FROM dummy_schema.users AS userData
LEFT JOIN dummy_schema.positions AS p ON userData.position = p.id
WHERE id = 1;
```